# iosopendev - preferences framework file not found error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cydia, cydia-substrate

I want to create a preferencesLoader bundle using iOSOpenDev but when I create a new project, in the .h file there is an error :

```
#import <Preferences/Preferences.h>  //Error: File not found
```

I tried to import the framework manually after downloading it from github but it stills the same error.

EDIT: after creating the project, Preferences framework is already inside the frameworks folder but it's showing in red.

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the framework on the build phases of your target (not the project) on the Link library with libraries.

Go to build settings of your target (not project) and on the library search path add the library path.

On the Headers search path add the path for your h files.

Wish it helps